# Pulling parts of info from a single var in JQuery

Tags: xml, jquery, xhtml

I am using jquery to pull in a XML feed. The problem is that all the information comes in under a single node:

```
    <description><![CDATA[<div class="element element-date first">
    Friday, 09 August 2013</div>
<div class="element element-textarea">
    <p>CES MMA Champion Mike "The Beast" Campbell (13-4, Providence, RI.), Dinis "Sweetbread" Paiva (E. Providence, RI.), Keith "Sonic Boom" Jeffrey (9-2, Pawtucket, RI.) and more!</p></div>
<div class="element element-link last">
    <a href="http://www.ticketmaster.com/ces-mma-presents-live-cagefighting-lincoln-rhode-island-08-09-2013/event/01004ACBB23C9DC4?artistid=1765605&majorcatid=10004&minorcatid=830" title="Click here to buy tickets!" target="_blank" >Click here to buy tickets!</a></div>]]></description>
```

I can pull this information in and get it to display just fine. What I need to do is pull a very specific part of this node, The date:

```
<div class="element element-date first">
        Friday, 09 August 2013</div>
```

I am not sure on how to get this information so I will post the jquery code I am working on and see if anyone can help me figure out a solution:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var i = 0;
    var title = [];
    var temp = [];
    var desc = [];
    var $divElements = $('.element element-date first');

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://twinriver.com/index.php/entertainment/twin-river-event-center/feed/rss/events/event-center?format=feed",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xml) {
            $(xml).find('item').each(function () {
                title[i] = $(this).find('title').text();
                desc[i] = $(this).find('description').text();
                i++;
                //alert(i);
            });
            //this is where im trying to get it to pull the info i need.
            for (var x = 0; x < i; x++) {
                alert($(desc[x]).find($divElements).val());
            }
            for (var t = 0; t < i; t++) {
                //      
                $('#EventList').append('<span class="title">' + title[t] + '</span>' + '<br />' + '<br />' + '<span>' + desc[t] + '<br />' + '<hr />');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

---

Update 07/03/2013:

Been trying to use the solutions presented by the replies with no luck. The alert comes up with one of two items, its blank or reads "undefined". I have also tried using something like the following:

```
eDate[i] = $(this).find('description').find('.element.element-date.first').html();

            alert(eDate[i]);
```

I added the `var eDate = [];` with the rest of the declared variables

Could it cause a problem the fact that the info im trying to get is not wrapped in a

tag or ?
If so is there anyway around having to add them? I dont think I can really edit the incoming data format but I will also research this as an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem lies in the fact that the content you're interested in is actually wrapped in a CDATA section, so you don't get a hierarchy in the dom tree of those nodes, but just one node representing the entire text inside the CDATA.
Further it's complicated by the fact that the content inside the CDATA doesn't have a root of it's own and therefore won't evaluate to a xml structure when passed into jquery.

a simple solution is to wrap the text() result from

`desc[i] = $(this).find('description').text();`

like this:

`desc[i] = "<rootnode>" + $(this).find('description').text() + "</rootnode>";`

then the alert will properly display the date after fixing the for loop expression to

`for (var t = 0; t < i; t++)`

and replacing the selector with just a plain.

`var divElements = '.element.element-date.first';`

There may be other and better solutions, but I tested this and it works.

**Update:** Felt code could use some cleaning. There's no reason to have all those arrays floating around with a little bit of restructuring.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://twinriver.com/index.php/entertainment/twin-river-event-center/feed/rss/events/event-center?format=feed",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function (xml) {
      $(xml).find('item').each(function () {
            var title = $(this).find('title').text();
            var desc = "<rootnode>" + $(this).find('description').text() + "</rootnode>";
            var date = $(desc).find('.element.element-date.first').text()
            $('#EventList').append('<span class="title">' + title + '</span>' + '<br />' + '<br />' + '<span>' + date + '<br />' + '<br />');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.element.element-date.first').each(function() {
  $(this).text(); // In each iteration this will get you the date
});
```

That way you don't need to write your own loop, (see the [.each() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/each/)) the other problem you were having is that when you see class="class1 class2 class3" you refer to that in jQuery and CSS with . before each class (since values separated by spaces in the class attribute are functionally different CSS classes).

Comment: How would I go about having that call the desc[] var because that is where the information is stored?

Comment: ah, i misinterpreted your code, Boris' answer includes the key bits that i missed!

Answer (score 0):

Your selector should be like this -

```
var $divElements = $('.element.element-date.first');
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass a selector to `find` instead of a jQuery object

```
var divSelector = '.element.element-date.first';
...
        for (var x = 0; t <= i; x++) {
            alert($(desc[t]).find(divSelector).text());//try also $.parseHTML(desc[t])
        }
```